# How to use MongoDB C# Driver to update property in object array and top property

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Currently I have this class

```
    public class Parent
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public DateTime TestDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
        public string NoChangeProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

And I updated this document with this update definition

```
var def = Builders<Parent>.Update
         .SetOnInsert(o => o.CreatedDateTimeUtc, DateTime.UtcNow)
         .Set(o => o.UpdatedDateTimeUtc, DateTime.UtcNow)
         if (parent.Children is { Count: > 0 })
         {
            definition = definition.Set(p => p.Children, parent.Children);
         }
```

This definition will replace **Children** List with new value.

Question: Is it possible to have an update definition to update Parent property and for the **Children** List, I don't want to update the **NoChangeProperty**?